# CouchBase logging in spring application

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I am using couchbase java sdk 1.1 in my spring application and the couchbase client logs to the standard output.

How can i disable the couchbase client from logging? I use 1 log4j.xml file to configure the logging in all the modules of my application but the couchbase client seems to ignore that file and log anyway to the tomcat stdout.

I have found no solutions in the couchbase java sdk manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in this document:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/java-api-configuring-logging.html

Just be sure to set the

> net.spy.log.LoggerImpl environment

variable to

> net.spy.memcached.compat.log.Log4JLogger

to be able to use Log4J.

You can do it programmatically using the following code:

```
System.setProperty("net.spy.log.LoggerImpl", "net.spy.memcached.compat.log.Log4JLogger");
```